# Pairs of ideals in an abelian category similar to torsion pairs

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, modules, torsion-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. In the context of my work I am considering pairs of ideals $(\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{J})$ in $\mathcal{A}$ with the following properties:

1. $\quad \mathcal{I} \mathcal{J} := \{ \varphi \psi \mid \varphi \in \mathcal{I}, \psi \in \mathcal{J}\}= 0$,
2. $\quad \mathcal{I} \mathcal{J}' = 0$ implies $\mathcal{J}' \subseteq \mathcal{J}$, and
3. $\quad \mathcal{I}' \mathcal{J} = 0$ implies $\mathcal{I}' \subseteq \mathcal{I}$.

Those properties are very similar to the properties of a torsion pair $(\mathcal{T}, \mathcal{F})$ in $\mathcal{A}$. In fact one can show that the pair of ideals generated by the identity morphisms of objects in $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ respectively fufills the properties. My question is:

Are such pairs of ideals studied in the literature? In particular I am interested in the case when $\mathcal{A}$ is a module category.

Comment: What is the definition of ideal here? Families of subgroups of the Hom objects or is there something different?

Comment: A family of morphisms of the category, which is closed under addition and closed under composition from the right and left from morphisms that may be outside of the ideal (similar to ideals of rings).